# Objective C IDE For Windows

Tags: java, objective-c, ide, java-native-interface, native

What would be the best IDE for Objective C for me on a Windows computer?  The main reason I want to use this is to create .dll libraries for JNI use.  Would JNI allow the .dlls to be cross platform even if I used Visual Studio C++ for example?  I've tried Eclipse for C/C++ but it doesn't work properly, I get a launch error.

Comment: There is no such a thing. You can use for example Sublime Text 2 or just a Notepad++ with GNUStep to type and compile your Objective C code, but there is no IDE for Objective C on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one? Its maybe not a complete IDE, but still could help?

http://www.editrocket.com/features/objective-c_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use code::blocks ide. 
It comes with Wizards to help you set up projects like:SFML 2d graphics or sdl even Opengl and more!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for participating to Stack Overflow, however please note that the question you have answered is off-topic as per the [help/on-topic] since it is a tool request. Answers to such questions tend to be of [poor quality](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and quickly become stale (what might have been a good resource two years ago may simply not exist anymore). You can flag this question as off-topic by clicking the "flag" link once you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @NickA Thank you for teaching us all, Nick! May I query whether there is a place we can go for tool discussion? Stack Overflow is the perfect place for asking developer questions, it would be great it if there were a forum here on tools. -sulu

Comment: @SuLlewellyn you could try [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) make sure you check what's on topic first though

Comment: @NickA Thank you! I will do so.